# Where can I get glibc?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc

I want to deploy some application to linux OS, so I installed a recent version of Ubuntu and gcc/IDE (13.10-amd64, gcc ver 4.8.1, Eclipse 3.8.1).

Then I try to install Intel's ICC to my computer, however, the ICC installer tell me it requires glibc to install properly and they cannot find this glibc library in my system so the installation cannot continue.

I then use search command to find if there are glibc library for Ubuntu, however it return no results for this library, and I use synaptic to search, it returns nothing besides some doc files for this glibc library either.

Can anyone tell me where can I get this glibc library? thanks.

UPDATE: 
The installer show me the following warning:

32-bit libraries not found on this system.

This product release requires the presence of 32-bit compatibility libraries when running on Intel(R) 64 architecture systems. One or more of these libraries could not be found:

libstdc++ (including libstdc++6)
glibc
libgcc

Without these libraries, the compiler and the debugger will not function properly. Please refer to Release Notes for more information.

Comment: `glibc` is the GNU standard C library. The package name is likely to be something like "libc6". It's preinstalled, but perhaps you don't have the version that ICC expects. You say the installer "tell me it requires glibc to install properly"; please update your question to show the *exact* (copy-and-pasted) error message.

Answer (score 1):

To prepare my 64-bit Ubuntu installs to be able to build 32-bit binaries, I run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
```

It's possible that only the 2nd install is necessary (it might include the first by dependencies), but following good cargo-cult practices, I just run both.